# debug or find the missing component when there is no error, and you misspelled it with a capital letter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I have a lot of experience with vanilla JavaScript, but I'm just learning React. I would like to understand how to debug or identify what's wrong when there are no errors in the browser console, but the component is not being displayed. I have installed the React DevTools extension, but I'm unsure how it can help
I have this :  notice the capital "E" in Element: ,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorPage from "./components/ErrorPage";
import Home from "./components/Home";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    Element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [{ index: true, element: <Home /> }],
  },
]);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

App.js :

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
function App() { return ( <div className="container "> <div className="row"> <div className="col"> <h1 className="mt-3">Go watch movie</h1> </div> <div className="col text-end"> <a href="#!"><span className="badge bg-success">Login</span></a> </div> <hr className="md-3"></hr> </div>
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-2">
      <nav>
        <div className="list-group">
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Home</a>
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Movies</a>
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Genres</a>
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Add Movie</a>
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Manage Catalogue</a>
          <a href="#!" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">GraphQL</a>
        </div>
      </nav>          
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-10">
      <Outlet/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
); }
export default App;
```

The 'list-group' does not appear in the browser until I fix the element from `<App/>` to `<App/>,`. What worries me the most is that there is no error message or anything in the browser to help me find the problem. How should I debug it next time?

Comment: This is something that typescript would help with, it'd warn you that `Element` isn't a valid or expected property of the [_RouteObject_](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) type that's expected.

Comment: no javascript solution ?